# Can't share object inside ES6 class that's registered as an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following Angular code where i'm trying to share some service across the whole class:

```
class StreamingService {

  constructor($q, someService) {
    this.$q = $q;
    this.someService = someService;

    this.getMenu = function () {
      return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        someService.client.getId().load(123)
          .then(function (data) {
            resolve(data.menu);

          }, function (err) {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    };

  }

  getStreaming() {
    let { $q, getMenu, someService } = this;

    someService.onConnected(function () {

      getMenu()
        .then(function (menu) {
          return menu.map(function (elem) {
            if (elem.id === 'live') {
              return elem.livestream[0];
            }
          });
        });

    });
  }

}

StreamingService.$inject = ['$q', 'someService'];
export default angular.module('services.streaming-service', [])
  .service('streamingService', StreamingService)
  .name;
```

But I get a 'someService' is not defined. When I console log 'this' from inside the getStreaming property I don't get the elements in the constructor but the other properties of the class. Do you know whats happening?
Thanks (:

Comment: How are you calling your constructor/method?

Comment: `someService` never define as angular service

Comment: @Zamboney I'm using webpack so the service is defined somewhere else and (I've checked) is inside the scope of the class

Answer (score 1):

Would comment if I could because I am not certain this is the answer, but I am under 50 rep so I cannot.

I am not too familiar with Angular, but in plain javascript, this will not work because you defined your variable within the constructor to be public.

Refer to some service by using `this.someService` and it should work (within the `getStreaming()` method)

**EDIT**: It is possible that `this` does not refer to the object by the way, for nested functions this happens to me. To avoid it make a private variable within the constructor like `var self = this;` and refer to that to point at the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing exactly that when I'm doing let { $q, getMenu, someService } = this; if I'm getting you right

Comment: You might very well be, as said I am not familiar with how angular works. In plain javascript if I was to need to reference the field defined by your constructor I would have to use this.someService. Try it, maybe it ends up working. Other thing that, I will again assume is specific to angular is the way that constructor and getStreaming are defined as just <name> () without ever saying they are functions. Again could be angular.js thing.

Comment: Oh one more thing hit me. This could be your problem. Editing the answer post.

Comment: @Dellirium "without ever saying they are functions" - that's [ES6 classes](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-classes/), and `let {...}=this` is destructuring, both are features of modern JS.

Comment: @NIckolay thank you for the link, it is a nice read! Sheds some light into what is done there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class StreamingService {
  constructor(v) { this.v = v; }
  getStreaming() { let {v} = this; console.log(v) } 
}

var s = new StreamingService(5);
s.getStreaming(); //prints 5
```

... and the angular "services" are supposed to instantiate your class with `new`, as in the example above, so there doesn't seem anything wrong in the setup you've described so far.

I'd take a closer look at the `this` object in the inspector, as *"I don't get the elements in the constructor but the other properties of the class."* seems to indicate the `this` is bound to the prototype object for the class(?).

I'd also ensure that your class constructor was called as you expect.

I'd also set a breakpoint in the debugger to see how your class method was invoked, and where this `this` object comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The service was ok indeed, there was a problem in the way I was calling the service from my directive. Somehow the class was never initiated by angular. I'll leave an answer in the post for future reference in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @keyserfaty you could post a separate answer yourself and accept it, that's how it usually works on SO. And if my post helped, feel free to upvote it ;)